# Apache linked directories with PHP execution

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following code in ://localhost/.htaccess...

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .css .js

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .*\/scripts(.+) scripts$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule .*\/themes(.+) themes$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule !\.(css|xhtml|xml|zip)$ rewrite.php
```

**Goal:** To be able to use files in the ://localhost/scripts/ and ://localhost/themes/ directories for more than one site. Using the QSA flag I've been able to get both the directory and files (from both directories) to be accessible.

So...

://localhost/site1/scripts/

://localhost/site2/scripts/

...both access...

://localhost/scripts/

...and all the files in the directory as well of course.

**The Problem:** I'm not sure how to adapt the PHP execution in .js and .css files with this setup. In my current setup I have the files override the mime/media type using PHP. I have tried reordering the code around unsuccessfully so I'm not sure this is an order-of-execution problem. JavaScript files in example are being served as "application/x-httpd-php5" instead of actually executing PHP.

**Clarifications**

- The rewrite rule for file extensions is truncated intentionally so ignore that.
- This has absolutely nothing to do with redirects.
- I have tried symbolic links however apparently the alias command only works in the server configuration.
- Presume I have absolutely no access to the server configuration, I can only use .htaccess (I need to mirror this eventually in a live environment on shared hosting).
- I have rearranged the commands and have even used separate .htaccess files in numerous combinations.

Comment: I've read this three times now, and I can't figure out what problem you are trying to resolve.  Could you provide for clarification(1) path you're trying to get to, (2) the path you think it should map to, and (if possible, 3) the /var/log/apache/error.log entry showing what it tried to remap the path to instead?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, either. What kinds of issues are you encountering in the PHP files? Are you sure this is the way to go?

Comment: JavaScript files in example are being served as "application/x-httpd-php5" instead of actually executing PHP. Sorry for not clarifying that specifically.

Comment: Mmm, so you are getting the pure uninterpreted PHP code, correct?

Comment: @Pekka Yes, if I "download" the file and look at the source I see the PHP code along with the JavaScript.

Comment: NOTE - I've figured this out but due to enforced time restraints on newer accounts I can't post it for a while longer; I will post the answer when it allows me though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I somehow ended up mixing up *AddHandler* and *AddType*!

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .js
AddType text/javascript .js

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .*/scripts(.+) scripts$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule .*/themes(.+) themes$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(|site1/|site2/|file\.php) - [L]
RewriteRule !\.(css|xhtml|xml|zip)$ rewrite.php
```

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, if I "download" the file and look at the source I see the PHP code along with the JavaScript.

Then your `AddType` string is incorrect.

The easiest way might be asking the provider for the exact required string - it varies from server to server.

I personally wouldn't do this at all, though: It causes all css and js files to be parsed by the PHP interpreter, which isn't nice for server resources. I would much rather point to a `.css.php` file, or create individual `mod_rewrite` rules pointing to PHP files only for the style sheets that you really need PHP in.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the correct answer, I've done a lot of research and that is the correct handler for PHP. In my current configuration the handler works correctly 100% of the time. The issue is either order of execution, placement of the handler or something else that I'm not yet aware of. Also in regards to benchmarking my requests execute in about 60ms total locally while many web servers take upwards of 400ms. I'm trying this out locally first though I've also been using the handler live on my site for over a year. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: @John if the same handler works on your system, then the reason must be something else, agreed. Re performance thouzgh, it's not that much about speed as it is about memory consumption.

Comment: Then do you know of any tools that can show memory consumption in PHP please?